# Application Insights in .net core API + WebJob

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-webjobs, .net-core-3.1

We have a .net core (3.1) API connected to Application Insights with `AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry` in Startup's ConfigureServices, as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core).

We also have a web job in the same API. The logging there does not work without an extra configuration. For it to work, we connected again to Application Insights with `.AddApplicationInsightsWebJobs` in Program.cs, as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started#initialize-the-application-insights-logging-provider).

However, if the configuration for the web job is applied, we stop receiving API's logs of type "request" and "dependency". Without those also other Applications Insights features aren't available, like the application map.

Are we doing anything wrong or missing anything for having Application Insights working for both the API and the web job?

Comment: You can refer to a similar issue on GitHub: [Dependencies not logged for Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights newer than 2.0.25](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/2781)

Comment: You can also open an issue on GitHub: [azure-webjobs-sdk](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues)

Comment: Thank you for the hint, @DeepDave-MT.
For those interested, here is the opened issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/2805
The issue mentioned in a comment above is not related. My versions are different from the ones mentioned in the issue.